# Getting Stackoverflow exception while hitting the service endpoint

Tags: c#, api, web-applications, controller

While hitting the one of the end point of my services (using postman), I'm getting the below exception (Before even coming to the controller.).

[image]

Not sure exact issue, Below are the Api and its end point details, tried to figure it out from long time still not able to find the root cause.

[image]
[image]

Any kind of support is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please check the full stack trace of the exception (click on the view details and expand the exception to see stack trace)? StackOverflow should be raised by framework as a method is calling itself or hierarchy in a loop.

Comment: Yeah I do know the reason why actually that exception will be raised but not sure in this case. and we checked the stack trace as well, but it is null.

Comment: Have you try to check other API (same problem or not) ? and also check your connection string setting in your web config ?

Comment: other Apis are working fine. Issue with only this Api only. Yeah no issue web.config file connection string.